# How is a process able to acquire many CPU cycles?

Tags: c++, c, cpu-cycles

I noticed that VLC media player acquired at times up to 98% of the CPU when performing a file conversion from MP4 to MP3. My understanding is that the OS tries to balance the time each process gets so this captured my attention. I have a feeling that programs like disk defragmenters and antivirus may also require processor cycles on such a magnitude. How it achieved in code( C,C++)?

Comment: A process can use more compute resources on a CPU with multiple cores by using multiple threads.  But I think the effect you are seeing is normal behaviour of the scheduler (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)); not something achieved through the code (though the scheduler has some parameters that can be client set; `nice` achieves this in linux.

Comment: Because a conversion does much work, the more work you do the more resources are needed to finish it. I doubt that defragmenting will use much CPU, it is rather I/O bound, i.e. it depends on the performance of your hard drive.

Comment: Why would antivirus or defrag cause 100% CPU load? Usually antivirus software simply monitor file accesses in the background. And defrag-like programs usually run ONLY if the system is idle since they do something that is less important than pretty much ANYTHING else.

Comment: You want a program that uses 100% CPU? `int main(){while(1); return 0;}`.

Comment: @Zeta: On a single core processor, that would use 100% CPU if no other processes or threads were competing for CPU time. On a multicore processor, the loop would only use 1/NumberOfCores of the CPU. But if you started multiple threads and ran that loop in each, then you could use near 100% CPU.

Comment: Given that your computer is doing several billion operations per second, and that updating the pretty graph you're looking at every couple of seconds takes next to no time, isn't it *natural* that the only program actually doing any *work* on your system gets all those otherwise unused clock cycles? If I'm running a compile / test suite in parallel, VLC doesn't get 100% anymore...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on OS, but *OS tries to balance the time each process gets* is usually not the prime objective.

A smart scheduler will instead utilise the available CPU(s) while still be responsive for higher priority things like user input and hardware events. A nicely behalves thread will also withdraw its time slice before its cpu quota if there is no more work to do (e.g. blocking for event), otherwise upon deadline the scheduler may take over the cpu(preempt) and give other thread a chance to execute.

You may set the thread priority as a hint to the scheduler, that may affect the *take over condition*, but it all depends on the scheduler and OS internals.

Simply put, you don't need to do special things to utilise a cpu core, if you have intensive calculation, the OS give the most to you.